# Drawing marker path line on Google map overlay canals and rivers

Tags: android, google-maps, path, android-jetpack-compose, draw

I'm building an app that save boat's locations on a map. I can draw markers on the Google map compose box (see screenshot) but I would like to link them via a path.
I can assume that rivers and canals are always close to a towpath so I can use the Google Traffic APIs and get the walking route but that is not the best solution.
How can I detect water on Google map? Is there a way to do that so I can draw a line on top of canals and rivers?
I don't want to draw the polyline manually but doing it programmatically giving at least 2 LatLng points on the map.
The green on the map is a canal in London.
[image]

Comment: My thoughts on this is you can draw either a custom made polyline or a polygon yourself. Here's some references for you to see: [Polygon Documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-polygon.html), [Polylines Documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-polyline.html)

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Composable Function to Add a Polyline to a Map

You can use the [Polyline](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-polyline.html) composable function to create your own path on top of a river/canals.

I tried to reproduce an example using my own `LatLng` values to create a path on top of the river.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
val center = LatLng(14.563063, 121.060071)
val marker1 = LatLng(14.565079, 121.055974)
val marker2 = LatLng(14.561618, 121.064759)
val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
   position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(center, 15f)
}
GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
) {
    Marker(
        state = MarkerState(position = marker1),
        title = "Marker 1",
        snippet = "First Marker!"
    )
    Marker(
        state = MarkerState(position = marker2),
        title = "Marker 2",
        snippet = "Second Marker!"
    )
    Polyline(
        points = listOf(
            LatLng(14.565079, 121.055974),
            LatLng(14.565223, 121.056668),
            LatLng(14.564586, 121.059012),
            LatLng(14.563079, 121.060970),
            LatLng(14.561647, 121.062719),
            LatLng(14.561152, 121.064543),
            LatLng(14.561618, 121.064759)
        )
        ,color = Color.Black
    )
}
```

And here's what it looks like in my emulator:

[image: Sample of maps compose using polyline]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but this works only if you manually draw the polyline. I need a way to know where is a river and then draw a polyline between 2 points.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the Google Maps SDK for Android have such a feature, maybe you can try filing a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker) for this.